# How to prevent pandas resample from resampling id columns

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with id columns (site_id,type_id,equipment_id), a timestamp and a value as below.

```
>>>print(df.head())
site_id type_id equipment_id    timestamp                           value 
47      9       332859965468    2018-07-04  10:30:04.052000+10:00   23.000000
47      9       332859965468    2018-07-04  10:30:04.064000+10:00   22.050505
47      9       332859965468    2018-07-04  10:30:04.090000+10:00   26.046154
47      9       332859965468    2018-07-04  10:30:04.101000+10:00   22.000000
47      9       332859965468    2018-07-04  10:30:04.113000+10:00   191.989868
```

I'm trying to resample within each (site_id,type_id,equipment_id) group using the following code

```
>>> df = df \
...     .set_index(['timestamp']) \
...     .sort_values(['site_id','type_id','equipment_id','timestamp']) \
...     .groupby(['site_id','type_id','equipment_id']) \
...     .resample('15T') \
...     .mean()
```

I'm getting unexpected results, all of the id values from the index have been duplicated. It seems to be using the dtype rather than whether the column is in the index or not to perform the aggregation? Am I doning something wrong?

```
                                                            site_id type_id equipment_id    value
site_id type_id equipment_id    timestamp
47      9       332859965468    2018-07-04 10:30:00+10:00   47.0    9.0     3.328600e+11    58.718625
                                2018-07-04 10:45:00+10:00   47.0    9.0     3.328600e+11    59.175833
                                2018-07-04 11:00:00+10:00   47.0    9.0     3.328600e+11    59.238318
                                2018-07-04 11:15:00+10:00   47.0    9.0     3.328600e+11    58.982763
```

Edit: I've noticed adding .reset_index(drop=True) removes the duplicate columns - but the issue now is the integer id columns have been converted to floats?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be intended behavior. The reason is that `.resample(.)` may yield rows that have `NaN`s due to empty resampling buckets. To see this, just decrease the resampling period. Perhaps you want to be able to filter by e.g. `result.site_id.notnull()`. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to a `MultiIndex` if the index isn't sorted. If you'd like to have the index looking "clean" again, you could do:

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

For instance,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.rand(5, 4),
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(i, j) for i, j in zip(np.random.choice(['a', 'b'], 5), np.random.choice(['x', 'y'], 5))])
)
print(df)
print(df.sort_index())
```

which produces:

```
            0         1         2         3
a x  0.198659  0.616800  0.438903  0.830216
  y  0.649111  0.860940  0.440068  0.044067
b x  0.178537  0.601514  0.898179  0.140358
  y  0.444738  0.393664  0.877928  0.913228
a x  0.369067  0.944636  0.740877  0.751681
            0         1         2         3
a x  0.198659  0.616800  0.438903  0.830216
  x  0.369067  0.944636  0.740877  0.751681
  y  0.649111  0.860940  0.440068  0.044067
b x  0.178537  0.601514  0.898179  0.140358
  y  0.444738  0.393664  0.877928  0.913228
```

Comment: That's not really what I'm seeing though - in my example above the site_id column appears twice. Once in the index and once in the dataframe? If I change it from numeric to string it works as expected

Comment: Ah sorry, yes I see.